# Thomashaertel's library as a multi-select spinner

Tags: android

I have been using **Thomashaertel's** library as a multi-select spinner.

> Unless I select all the items, there is no issue but when I select all
>   the items, It doesn't display the selected item in the textview.

I tried looking for the solution but failed.
Lemme know if anyone has resolved that issue.

This is how I am creating the list. Is there some issue with the way I am creating it or there is some issue with the Library itself??

```
spinner = new MultiSpinner(context);
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
           R.array.data_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

I am getting the array from the String resource file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, even I had the same problem a few weeks back. It seems to be an issue of the library. I had raised the issue on Github too but no response.
I don't have the solution for this one but have a **hack**.

Instead of using the multispinner's textview,

> you can make use of regular textview and add onClickListener to it.

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                spinner.callOnClick(); // call spinner's onClick when textview is clicked
            }
```

This lets you render the dialog with multiselect options.
 Now maintain a stringbuilder.

> Set the adapter on the spinner and override onItemsSelected(boolean)

and follow the below code

```
public void onItemsSelected(boolean[] selected) {
                    stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                        if (selected[i]) {
                            list.add(String.valueOf(adapter.getItem(i).toString())); //get the list of selected items
                            if (stringbuilder.length() == 0) {
                                stringbuilder.append(adapter.getItem(i));
                            } else {
                                stringbuilder.append(",").append(adapter.getItem(i));
                            }
                            textView.setText(String.valueOf(stringbuilder));
                        } else {
                            list.remove(adapter.getItem(i).toString()));
                        }
                    }
                    if (stringbuilder.length() == 0) {
                        textView.setText(" Make your selection");
                    }
            }
```

It looks clean compared to the view that multispinner gives and also you have to customize 
advantage.

Hope it is useful

Comment: thanks. i tried this hack and it worked for now. But is there another workaround if this is a library issue? like using some other library or something like that?

Comment: You can search for other open source Libraries in Github as per your requirement. [Check another similar library](https://github.com/pratikbutani/MultiSelectSpinner)